# jQuery does not find <div> by class

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to display my animated controls relative to the position of my form's header.

```
<div class="page-header container">
```

From within jQuery, I am trying to show messages with this function:

```
function showMessage(stype, title, message) {
  var position = $('.page-header container').offset.top;
  if (typeof position == 'undefined') {
    position = '50px';
    alert(position);
  } else {
    position = "'" + position + "px'";
  }
  $('.' + stype).animate({ top: position }, 500);
}
```

Every time I get **alert('50px')**.

Since I am identifying with a CLASS instead of an ID, I thought I would try reading in the collection of all items in class `'.page-header container'`:

```
function showMessage(stype, title, message) {
  var items = $('.page-header container');
  var position = items[0].offset.top;
  if (typeof position == 'undefined') {
    position = '50px';
    alert(position);
  } else {
    position = "'" + position + "px'";
  }
  $('.' + stype).animate({ top: position }, 500);
}
```

This time, it seems that `items` is undefined.

What have I overlooked?

Comment: Change $('.page-header container') to $('.page-header .container')

Comment: Why are you checking `typeof something == 'undefined'` here? When the variable is declared but uninitialized it's set to the language constant `undefined` . The `typeof` operator is to be used when the variable might not be _declared_. In general while I'm at this - avoid `==` and prefer `===` unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: until T.J. fixed my problem below, `typeof position` **was** undefined. My question here was to find out why.

Comment: @jp2code right, it _was_ undefined but it was _actually_ undefined and not undeclared. The typeof operator works on a value even if it was not declared (not just assigned to, but not even declared). So if you do `var x;` it's perfectly safe to do `if(x===undefined)`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: So, what is the preferred way to check that I **CAUGHT** something with [jQuery] and that I am not trying to assign with a null value?

Comment: jQuery is just a library and has nothing to do with this here. In JavaScript - the language you run your code using the jQuery library in - it'd be enough to do `  if (position === undefined) {` because of the `var position` statement above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two problems with this line:

```
var position = $('.page-header container').offset.top;
```

First, it's looking for an element with the tag `container` *within* an element with the class `page-header`. The space indicates a [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators). Second, [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset) is a function, not a property.

I think you meant:

```
var position = $('.page-header.container').offset().top;
```

That looks for an element that has both of the classes `page-header` **and** `container`, and calls `offset` (because it's a function), and then uses the `top` property of the object it returns.

Comment: That's amazing! I got this working after only your 3rd or 4th revision. :)

Comment: Wow, I just upvoted this and it went from 0 to 7 :O That's a lot for a minute. Anyway - off topic aside this is probably what you want OP, and if you want a `in a` relation you can use `.page-header .container`

Comment: I don't understand why I have to wait so long to accept a great answer, though.